# Wrap Bluebird promise in mPromise

Tags: mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am using mPromises throughout a service and in order to maintain a consistent interface (i.e end() for ex) I have a need to wrap a promisfied Bluebird function in it - I am not too familiar with mPromise though and am not succeeding. Here's what I have:

```
var p = new mPromise();
p.chain(Bluebird.promisify(easypost.Address.create_and_verify, easypost.Address)(params.recipient)
    .then(function(res) {
      return p.resolve(res);
    }, function(err) {
      return p.reject(err);
    });
)
return p;
```

It's a but contrived but the general idea. This yields this error:

```
[TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap bluebird promises inside `mPromise`s.

Promises in Mongoose are Promises/A+ compliant and so are bluebird promises - you can simply mix and match them and they are guaranteed to act consistently. You can pass a bluebird promise where an mPromises is expected and vice versa.

That said - I'd go the other way about it and promisify `Mongoose.prototype` since bluebird promises are easy to debug and are much faster.

If you must - you can do:

```
var p = new mPromise();
p.fulfill().chain(bluebirdPromise);
```

Also, don't call `promisify` for every request - this is expensive - do it once per prototype.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I wanted to wrap was because each lib uses its own promise extensions and mPromise has `end()` which Bluebird doesn't. I am working on something that used to be strickly Mongoose hence the use of `end`. Though now I think I might revisit and just go for standard.

Comment: Is there value in using Bluebird to wrap Mongoose even with mPromise being there?

Comment: In bluebird, like in Q and other libraries `.end` is called `.done` although bluebird figures out when you have an unhandled rejection on its own and will report it so things will work as you expect even if you forget a `done` it's also about 100 times faster, has long stack traces and much better support - so yeah I'd say it's probably best to use bluebird if you don't have another reason to stick to mpromise. @Yashua